# database-design-suggestions for saving payment gateway responses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am working on a marketplace app for hotel bookings. The model flow goes like this

Host `has_many` Hotels

Hotel `has_many` Rooms

Room & Guest `has_many` Bookings

The `Booking` model has fields with :room_id, :total_price, guest_id etc

Now comes the `payment` part.. Where should I keep the payment gateway responses like `payment_status`, `pg_error_message`? Is it good practice to keep those in booking model itself? Or should I create a new model for sale?

like... Booking `has_one` Sale

Is there a preferred approach here??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll need another model, because you can have more than one reponse like and more than one transaction.

```
3rd Cancelled, 2017-01-15
2nd Captured, 2016-12-01
1st Aprroved, 2016-12-01
```

So, if you have another relation you can register a more consistent responses, i don't know what information gateways will return in your country, but in Brazil we store something like this, i will show the models of my application!

```
Invoice
   price: float # Total price of invoice
   paid:bool # If is paid, i can have a method insted of store this in DB
   uuid: string # Some gateways need this
   ...

InvoicePayment
  payment_method: int # Payment Metod selected from user.
  gateway: string # Who process my payment.
  fees: float # Fees charged in this transaction
  transaction_token:string # ID and Token and whatever i need to  >>>     
  transaction_id:string    # identify the transaction on the gateway
  transaction_key:string   
  auth_code: string 
  captured:bool # I already captured this transaction?
  af_status: string # Anti Fraud response data
  af_score: string
  value: float   # value of transaction, imagine that i can receive a invoice in more than one transaction.
```

That's all, i'm sure that i have some particularities in my country, but i think that is a main idea.

Sya!

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am using papertrail gem to keep record of my model. In this case isnt that enough to keep data on the same model itself?

Comment: Yes, i don't like to use papertrail for this, but i'm sure it can be done!